# Dealing with twitter timestamps in R

Tags: r, date, twitter, time, data-science

I've got a dataset with tweets and the informations twitter provides about them. I need to transform my dates from the format given to one I can understand properly (preferentially using a function I can choose the format, since I might need to select the tweets by day of the week, time of the day or anything like that) using R, I'm just starting to learn the language.
the format I've got the dates in is:

```
1420121295000
1420121298000
```

I've researched a bit before answering and tried to use functions like as.POSIXct, as>POSIXlt and others, they all got me this error:

```
Error in as.POSIXct.default(date, format = "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y", : 
do not know how to convert 'date' to class "POSIXct"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format above is in epochs. Assuming this is in milliseconds since the epoch (you would have to double-check with the Twitter api), you can convert from epoch to UTC time using anytime function from the anytime package as shown below, which returns "2015-01-01 14:08:15 UTC."

```
 anytime(1420121295000*0.001) #times 0.001 to convert to seconds
 format(anytime(1420121295000*0.001), tz = "America/New_York", usetz=TRUE) #converting from UTC to EST timezone.
```

Comment: If i do it with my time stamp's vector, it sends me an error saying 
   
    "Error in FUN(left, right) : non-numeric argument to binary operator", 

it works if I do it with bare numbers like you said but when I throw in a variable it gets me this error (even if I pass date[1,1] as a param)

Comment: It may be that your timestamp is encoded as a factor/character rather than as a numeric. If its a factor, you can convert to a numeric using as.numeric(as.character(timestamp)) and if its encoded as a character, then use as.numeric(timestamp). See if this fixes the issue.

Comment: If i use the class command, it returns 

    "Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'".

If I use the 
as.numeric(as.character(date)), where date is my vector, I get 

    "Error in as.character(timestamp) : 
     cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'". 

And if I just use the as.numeric(date) I get 

    "[1] NA
    Warning message:
    NAs introduced by coercion"

Comment: Do you have a reproducible example/example of how you generated the timestamp list so I can play around with it? I think this is mainly an issue with how the timestamp is encoded, which I don't really know how to answer unless I have a sample example to test.

Comment: Solved it. Discovered that I had to use the operator $. I was selecting the column by using the index as in date[1] instead of date$datetime. Thank you for your help

Comment: Sure, glad you fixed it!